# cast decimal value to NULL if value is 0.000000

Tags: sql-server

I would like to handle the decimal values 0.000000 and NULL in null-able column both as NULL

For example:

```
case worthColumn
WHEN '0.000000' then NULL
WHEN NULL then NULL
ELSE worthColumn
END 
AS SumOfWorth
```

But the value 0.000000 always ends up in the result ?

Comment: Looks like your 0 values aren't exactly 0 (maybe they're something like 0.0000000001). Try rounding or casting to an integer and compare that result. Or use a less-than.

Comment: `nullif(worthColumn, 0)` or `CASE worthColumn WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE worthColumn END`

Comment: No WorthColumn is (decimal(20,3),NULL) so it holds both 0.000000 and NULL

Comment: Hi, remove ' ' in your when branch. The WHEN NULL then NULL is unuseful. Ok ELSE worthColumn

Answer (score 8):

If it's a decimal then you don't need to compare it to a string. Use `NULLIF`:

`NULLIF(worthColumn,0)`

If you use the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable(A DECIMAL(20,3));

INSERT INTO YourTable
VALUES (10),(1),(NULL),(0.000),(20);

SELECT *, NULLIF(A,0)
FROM YourTable
```

Then you get the following results:

```
╔════════╦══════════════════╗
║   A    ║ (No column name) ║
╠════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 10.000 ║ 10.000           ║
║ 1.000  ║ 1.000            ║
║ NULL   ║ NULL             ║
║ 0.000  ║ NULL             ║
║ 20.000 ║ 20.000           ║
╚════════╩══════════════════╝
```

(can't post an sqlfiddle right now because it's down for the moment)

Comment: If i use:  NULLIF(x.heildarvirdi_sjods,0) it ends up with values like 0.00000000, NULL and of cource some values like 8018.00000000. You are saying that 0.00000000 is actually not zero value (null) ?

Comment: @agh I'm not really following you. If the data type of the column is `decimal(20,3)`, then a value of `0` should be shown as `0.000`, not 8 decimal digits. And still `0` should be equal to `0.0000000` unless you are using another data type. You should post the table definition and some example data.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the quotes around the 0.000000:

```
case worthColumn
WHEN 0.000000 then NULL
WHEN NULL then NULL
ELSE worthColumn
END 
AS SumOfWorth
```

Having the quotes means you are comparing it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is numbers that are really close to zero but you don't see the extra digits.  Here are two ways to do what you want:

The numerical method:

```
case WHEN abs(worthColumn ) < 0.0000005 then NULL
     ELSE worthColumn
 END) AS SumOfWorth
```

The "make it a string" method:

```
(case when format(worthColumn, 6) = '0.000000' then NULL
      ELSE worthColumn
 END) AS SumOfWorth
```